# failed to display data in grid

Tags: c#

I've an old application written in VB6 which retrieved data fom Oracle db table and display in Grid. I m trying to achieve the same using C# but failed.

The basic idea is ... the grid has certain fixed rows starting with product details in first 2 columns and then Product grades in rest. Each time after I fill the grid I check if the product is changed .. if not then keep filling the same row and when the product is not same as previous one then go to next row and so on until the data is done.

This was working perfectly fine in VB6 but I m unable to achieve the same in C#.

Please help me!!

Thanks in advance

Rgds
Shekhar

```
        string l_merge = string.Empty;
        string l_grade = string.Empty;
        string l_pack = string.Empty;
        string l_usage = string.Empty;
        string l_spool=string.Empty;

        string strSQL = string.Empty;
        int rowNumber = 1;

        double boxes = 0;
        double aEven = 0;
        double aUnEven = 0;
        double bGrade = 0;
        double cGrade = 0;
        double ap3UnEven = 0;
        double ap7UnEven = 0;

        double rowTotal = 0;

        try
        {
            if (rbtBoxWise.Checked)
            {
                using (DataBaseConnection dbConn = new DataBaseConnection(this._dsn, this._username, this._password))
                {
                    strSQL = "Select MERGE, DENIER, GRADECODE, SPOOLCODE, USAGEFLAG, COUNT(BOXNUMBER) As Boxes " +
                             "From TBL_BOXINHAND Where PRODUCTCODE='D' " +
                             "Group By MERGE, DENIER, GRADECODE, SPOOLCODE, USAGEFLAG " +
                             "Order By MERGE, DENIER, GRADECODE, SPOOLCODE, USAGEFLAG";

                    OracleDataReader orReader = dbConn.ExecuteReader(strSQL);                     

                    if (orReader != null && orReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        dtyStock.Rows = 1;
                        while (orReader.Read())
                        {
                            dtyStock.Rows = dtyStock.Rows + 1;
                            dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 1).Text = orReader["MERGE"].ToString();
                            dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 2).Text = orReader["DENIER"].ToString();
                            //dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 3).Text = "DTY - " + orReader["ILTYPE"].ToString() + " - " + orReader["LUSTURE"].ToString() + " - " + orReader["HEATER"].ToString();

                            l_merge = orReader["MERGE"].ToString();

                            do
                            {
                                l_grade = orReader["GRADECODE"].ToString();
                                l_usage = orReader["USAGEFLAG"].ToString();
                                l_spool = orReader["SPOOLCODE"].ToString();

                                if (l_grade.StartsWith("A") && l_usage.StartsWith("E") && l_spool != "P3" && l_spool != "P7")
                                {
                                    aEven = aEven + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 4).Text = aEven.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (l_grade.StartsWith("A") && l_usage.StartsWith("L") && l_spool != "P3" && l_spool != "P7")
                                {
                                    aUnEven = aUnEven + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 5).Text = aUnEven.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (l_grade.StartsWith("A") && l_usage.StartsWith("L") && l_spool == "P3" && l_spool != "P7")
                                {
                                    ap3UnEven = ap3UnEven + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 6).Text = ap3UnEven.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (l_grade.StartsWith("A") && l_usage.StartsWith("L") && l_spool != "P3" && l_spool == "P7")
                                {
                                    ap7UnEven = ap7UnEven + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 7).Text = ap7UnEven.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (l_grade.StartsWith("B"))
                                {
                                    bGrade = bGrade + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 8).Text = bGrade.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }
                                else if (l_grade.StartsWith("C"))
                                {
                                    cGrade = cGrade + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                    dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 9).Text = cGrade.ToString();
                                    rowTotal = rowTotal + double.Parse(orReader["Boxes"].ToString());
                                }

                                if (orReader != null && orReader.HasRows)
                                {
                                    orReader.Read();
                                    if (l_merge != orReader["MERGE"].ToString())
                                    {
                                        dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 10).Text = rowTotal.ToString();
                                        rowNumber++;

                                        boxes = 0;
                                        aEven = 0;
                                        aUnEven = 0;
                                        bGrade = 0;
                                        cGrade = 0;
                                        ap3UnEven = 0;
                                        ap7UnEven = 0;
                                        rowTotal = 0;
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            while (orReader.HasRows);

                            if (!orReader.HasRows)
                            {
                                dtyStock.Cell(rowNumber, 10).Text = rowTotal.ToString();
                                rowNumber++;

                                boxes = 0;
                                aEven = 0;
                                aUnEven = 0;
                                bGrade = 0;
                                cGrade = 0;
                                ap3UnEven = 0;
                                ap7UnEven = 0;
                                rowTotal = 0;
                                break;
                            }    

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strSQL = string.Empty;
                        MessageBox.Show(this, "Nothing is packed between selected period!!", "Empty Records", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        refreshAll(this);
                    }
                    orReader.Close();
                }
            }
            else if (rbtNetWt.Checked)
            {
                using (DataBaseConnection dbConn = new DataBaseConnection(this._dsn, this._username, this._password))
                {
                    strSQL = "Select MERGE, DENIER, TWIST, LUSTURE, ILTYPE, HEATER, GRADECODE, PACKINGTYPECODE,SPOOLCODE, USAGEFLAG, SUM(NETWT) " +
                             "From TBL_BOXINHAND Where PRODUCTCODE='D' Order By MERGE " +
                             "Group By MERGE, DENIER, TWIST, LUSTURE, ILTYPE, HEATER, GRADECODE, PACKINGTYPECODE,SPOOLCODE, USAGEFLAG";

                    OracleDataReader orReader = dbConn.ExecuteReader(strSQL);
                    if (orReader != null && orReader.HasRows)
                    {
                        dtyStock.Rows = 1;
                        while (orReader.Read())
                        {

                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        strSQL = string.Empty;
                        MessageBox.Show(this, "Nothing is packed between selected period!!", "Empty Records", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                        refreshAll(this);
                    }
                    orReader.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                strSQL = string.Empty;
                MessageBox.Show(this, "Please choose either Box Wise or Net Wt Wise to continue!!", "Invalid Choice", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Exception", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: what problem you are facing? is it showing any error? did you use debugger to debug the code? debug and see in which line the problem is appearing and post the exact problem

Comment: thanks for reply. There are two errors in this code.
  1. At this point when I move the cursor to the next record...   
  if (orReader != null && orReader.HasRows)
  if the product is not yet changed then no issue but if the product is changed then then I reset all variable to 0 and exit from the "do/while" loop 
  after that when it goes back to first while loop it jumps to the next record and skip the one where a product changed is occured.

2. second issue is if is failed to check if its already EOF.